# RAD Websphere - EAR not picking up latest jar

Tags: websphere, ibm-rad

I am using RAD 7.0. My web application works with a jar(contains the backend code for our application) which undergoes frequent changes. But whenever I replace the jar in the WebInf/lib folder of the war and restart the server, it does not pick up the latest jar. It keeps referring to the previous jar. I have to undeploy, restart server several times to make the war pick up the latest jar. Has anyone come across this issue? Any pointers will be useful.

Many thanks,
RJ

Comment: Did you try to republish (from top of my head: rightclick your server in Servers view -> Publish...) ?
Application can also be configured to reload it's resources automatically. This is configurable in ibm-web-bnd.xml.

Answer (score 0):

Is your server configured with "Run with resources within the workspace"?

If so, switch to "Run with resources on the server" and see if this solves the problem.

I have had my share of RAD problems not picking up new code, especially on RAD 6.0 and 7.0; on RAD 7.5, IBM finally seemed to have a grip on these issues.

Answer (score 0):

You can also do a server clean to force the temp and work dirs to be cleaned and the code to be republished. RAD 7 has a problems and if you can upgrade to 7.5 many get resolved in that version.